# Django: How to get exception instance in error handlers

Tags: python, django, error-handling, django-middleware, django-errors

Django has [built-in default views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/views/) which are used automatically when exceptions such as `PermissionDenied`, `Http404`, `SuspiciousOperation`, etc. are raised. This is a convenient feature of Django which I love, but it seems to have a limitation.

I am raising an exception with a message: `raise PermissionDenied('You are not an xyz and have no access to foobar')`

Is there a context variable containing the original exception instance available in the templates (i.e. `403.html`) called by the original error handlers so that I can access the message?

If not, is it possible to get a hold of the original exception with a custom handler (`settings.handler403`, etc.) so I can inject it into the context?

---

NOTE: I believe I can create a custom middleware with `process_exception`, but I would like to avoid this if possible since my guess is I would be duplicating a lot of existing Django logic and it's cleaner to reuse it. Also, it looks like a custom `process_exception` would override the logging in `django.core.handlers.base` amongst other behaviors. Re-implementing all that just for the sake of injecting exception info into an error template seemed kind of silly.

Comment: There is already one for `403`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#error-handling

Comment: @karthikr Unfortunately, I already came across that and it seems like that's what the `settings.handler*` refers to. The problem is that the exception instance is [not being passed into the view as an argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/views/#http-forbidden-view). My question is whether there's a way to retrieve that exception instance, perhaps unconventionally via introspection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature has been implemented as [ticket 24733](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24733).

In Django 1.9 and later, the exception will be passed to the [error handlers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/views/#error-views).

Comment: Frankly kind of shocked that this simple use case had not been implemented until now but I'm glad it finally landed :)